# How to do a local search autocomplete as Apple's native map app does?

Tags: ios, iphone, mapkit, mklocalsearch

I have done an implementation by adopting most of the concept from Apple's sample code of the MKlocalSearch from [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/MapSearch/Introduction/Intro.html)

Currently for the auto complete, every time user is typing inside the search bar, I am sending a new request where I specified:

```
MkLocalSearchRequest.naturalLanguageQuery = searchBar.text
MkLocalSearchRequest.region = userlocation.region
```

But I get totally different set of response from sever comparing to Apple's default map app as shown in the image below

[image: My app]
[image: Apple Maps app]

Then I capture the traffic and find that my request goes to https://gsp-ssl.ls.apple.com/search.arpc while Apple's goes to 
https://gsp-ssl.ls.apple.com/auto_complete.arpc

Is there any way to tune the `MkLocalSearchRequest` to get the same set of response objects?

Comment: What is userlocation.region set to? Maybe that is limiting your query.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

MkLocalSearchRequest will not perform auto complete on your search string, perhaps because Apple wants to limit the number of requests from 3rd party apps.

In theory you could reverse-engineer the requests and responses to https://gsp-ssl.ls.apple.com/auto_complete.arpc and then perform those requests yourself, not using MkLocalSearchRequest at all. But that would probably lead to your app being rejected on the App Store.

Comment: That's exactly what I am thinking. Probably we have to switch to google map anyway.

Comment: I ended up using an Objective-C wrapper to Google Places, called SPGooglePlacesAutocomplete. Works great.

Comment: That's actually what we are going to do. But they have limits on the number of request per day. Once traffic picked up it would not be free anymore.

Comment: @TypingPanda can you point me towards where you found info on the limits of the free service please?

Answer (score 5):

@TypingPanda - I don't have enough points to comment directly but: beware of using the Google places API! Although perhaps not immediately obvious, Google's terms and conditions state that any visual representation of Google places data needs to occur on a Google Map. Hope everything works out!

Comment: Thanks @trdavidson, I will be careful with the terms and conditions. Thanks for the reminder.

Answer (score 2):

Since iOS 9.3 Apple has provided [MKLocalSearchCompleter](https://developer.apple.com/reference/mapkit/mklocalsearchcompleter).

> An MKLocalSearchCompleter object takes a partial search string and generates a list of potential completions. You use a search completer object to retrieve auto-complete suggestions for your own map-based search controls.

That's the class that uses https://gsp-ssl.ls.apple.com/auto_complete.arpc

It has quite similar syntax with `MkLocalSearchRequest`:

```
MKLocalSearchCompleter.queryFragment = searchBar.text
MKLocalSearchCompleter.region = userlocation.region
```

But for results you will need to listen delegate methods:

```
- (void)completerDidUpdateResults:(MKLocalSearchCompleter *)completer;
```